# javascript not working in I.E. 9 as well as Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Greetings fellow stackoverflow members,

I am having quite the dilemma as of late.  The code provided below is quite lengthy, however, most of it is duplicate code for each 3 main containers labeled (General, Kills, and Scores).

I am having issues with the javascript I have written up which coincides with jquery 1.9.1 - the slider doesn't slide - it works perfectly in Chrome, but doesn't in I.E.9 as well as Firefox for some reason...I've revised it all countless of times, but do not see any issues as to why it's not working in those browsers.  If you can look it over and provide me with what or where I am going wrong in my javascript I'd greatly appreciate it as I'm thinking it will be easier for you guys/gals to spot the issue since it's fresh to your eyes.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aeJtx/3/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
/* ===== Start of 'Slider - My Statistics (Achievements - General)' ===== */
$(function () {
    $('input.field').focus(function () {
        if (this.title == this.value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = this.title;
        }
    });
    var currentPage = 1;
    $('#slider_achievements_general .buttons_achievements_general span').on('click', function () {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("img").trigger("slidermove");
        }, 100);
        var fragments_count = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_general:eq(0)').find('.fragment_achievements_general').length;
        var fragment_width = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_general:eq(0)').find('.fragment_achievements_general').width();
        var perPage = 1;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(fragments_count / perPage);
        var stepMove = fragment_width * perPage;
        var container = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_general:eq(0)').find('.con_achievements_general');
        var firstPosition = 0;
        var lastPosition = -((numPages - 1) * stepMove);
        if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
            currentPage++;
            if (currentPage > numPages) {
                currentPage = 1;
                container.animate({
                    'left': firstPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
            currentPage--;
            if (currentPage < 1) {
                currentPage = numPages;
                container.animate({
                    'left': lastPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }
    });
});

/* ===== Start of 'Slider - My Statistics (Achievements - Kills)' ===== */
$(function () {
    $('input.field').focus(function () {
        if (this.title == this.value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = this.title;
        }
    });
    var currentPage = 1;
    $('#slider_achievements_kills .buttons_achievements_kills span').on('click', function () {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("img").trigger("slidermove");
        }, 100);
        var fragments_count = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_kills:eq(0)').find('.fragment_achievements_kills').length;
        var fragment_width = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_kills:eq(0)').find('.fragment_achievements_kills').width();
        var perPage = 1;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(fragments_count / perPage);
        var stepMove = fragment_width * perPage;
        var container = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_kills:eq(0)').find('.con_achievements_kills');
        var firstPosition = 0;
        var lastPosition = -((numPages - 1) * stepMove);
        if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
            currentPage++;
            if (currentPage > numPages) {
                currentPage = 1;
                container.animate({
                    'left': firstPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
            currentPage--;
            if (currentPage < 1) {
                currentPage = numPages;
                container.animate({
                    'left': lastPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }
    });
});

/* ===== Start of 'Slider - My Statistics (Achievements - Scores)' ===== */
$(function () {
    $('input.field').focus(function () {
        if (this.title == this.value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = this.title;
        }
    });
    var currentPage = 1;
    $('#slider_achievements_scores .buttons_achievements_scores span').on('click', function () {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("img").trigger("slidermove");
        }, 100);
        var fragments_count = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_scores:eq(0)').find('.fragment_achievements_scores').length;
        var fragment_width = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_scores:eq(0)').find('.fragment_achievements_scores').width();
        var perPage = 1;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(fragments_count / perPage);
        var stepMove = fragment_width * perPage;
        var container = $(this).parents('#slider_achievements_scores:eq(0)').find('.con_achievements_scores');
        var firstPosition = 0;
        var lastPosition = -((numPages - 1) * stepMove);
        if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
            currentPage++;
            if (currentPage > numPages) {
                currentPage = 1;
                container.animate({
                    'left': firstPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
            currentPage--;
            if (currentPage < 1) {
                currentPage = numPages;
                container.animate({
                    'left': lastPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
/* ===== Start of 'Achievement Details - (General)' ===== */
 #general_wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #333;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
#general_wrapper h2 {
    width: 626px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
    margin: 0 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    float: left;
    color: #AB9B68;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=315, strength=2, color=000000);
}
#slider_achievements_general {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #222;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
.buttons_achievements_general {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: -25px;
    z-index: 101;
}
.buttons_achievements_general span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 62px;
    padding: 34px 0 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttons_achievements_general span.prev {
    color: #111;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: 602px;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.buttons_achievements_general span.next {
    color: #111;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.holder_achievements_general {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    position: relative;
    top: -31px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.con_achievements_general {
    width: 100000px;
    height: 96px;
    position: absolute;
}
.fragment_achievements_general {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
/* ===== Start of 'General Medals Wrapper inside Fragment' ===== */
 #general_medals_wrapper {
    width: 576px;
    height: 96px;
    float: left;
}
/* ===== Start of 'Achievement Details - (Kills)' ===== */
 #kills_wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #333;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
#kills_wrapper h2 {
    width: 626px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
    margin: 0 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    float: left;
    color: #AB9B68;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=315, strength=2, color=000000);
}
#slider_achievements_kills {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #222;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
.buttons_achievements_kills {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: -25px;
    z-index: 101;
}
.buttons_achievements_kills span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 62px;
    padding: 34px 0 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttons_achievements_kills span.prev {
    color: #111;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: 602px;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.buttons_achievements_kills span.next {
    color: #111;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.holder_achievements_kills {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -31px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.con_achievements_kills {
    width: 100000px;
    height: 96px;
    position: absolute;
}
.fragment_achievements_kills {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
/* ===== Start of 'Kills Medals Wrapper inside Fragment' ===== */
 #kills_medals_wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
/* ===== Start of 'Achievement Details - (Scores)' ===== */
 #scores_wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #333;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
}
#scores_wrapper h2 {
    width: 626px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
    margin: 0 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    float: left;
    color: #AB9B68;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=315, strength=2, color=000000);
}
#slider_achievements_scores {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #222;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
.buttons_achievements_scores {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: -25px;
    z-index: 101;
}
.buttons_achievements_scores span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 62px;
    padding: 34px 0 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttons_achievements_scores span.prev {
    color: #111;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: 602px;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.buttons_achievements_scores span.next {
    color: #111;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.15em 0.45em 0.15em #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.holder_achievements_scores {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -31px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.con_achievements_scores {
    width: 100000px;
    height: 96px;
    position: absolute;
}
.fragment_achievements_scores {
    width: 577px;
    height: 96px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
/* ===== Start of 'Kills Medals Wrapper inside Fragment' ===== */
 #scores_medals_wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="general_wrapper">
     <h2>General</h2>

    <div id="slider_achievements_general">
        <div class="buttons_achievements_general"> <span class="next" title="Next">»</span>  <span class="prev" title="Previous">«</span>

        </div>
        <div class="holder_achievements_general">
            <div class="con_achievements_general">
                <div class="fragment_achievements_general">
                    <div id="general_medals_wrapper">
                        <p>Hi</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fragment_achievements_general">
                    <div id="general_medals_wrapper">
                        <p>World</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="kills_wrapper">
     <h2>Kills</h2>

    <div id="slider_achievements_kills">
        <div class="buttons_achievements_kills"> <span class="next" title="Next">»</span>  <span class="prev" title="Previous">«</span>

        </div>
        <div class="holder_achievements_kills">
            <div class="con_achievements_kills">
                <div class="fragment_achievements_kills">
                    <div id="kills_medals_wrapper">
                        <p>Hello</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fragment_achievements_kills">
                    <div id="kills_medals_wrapper">
                        <p>World</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scores_wrapper">
     <h2>Scores</h2>

    <div id="slider_achievements_scores">
        <div class="buttons_achievements_scores"> <span class="next" title="Next">»</span>  <span class="prev" title="Previous">«</span>

        </div>
        <div class="holder_achievements_scores">
            <div class="con_achievements_scores">
                <div class="fragment_achievements_scores">
                    <div id="scores_medals_wrapper">
                        <p>New</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fragment_achievements_scores">
                    <div id="scores_medals_wrapper">
                        <p>Slider</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's demo supposed to do? Looks identical to me in Chrome and FF..all 3 boxes have no content. Also be specific about what's not working

Comment: It slides for me (FF and IE9 mode under IE10)

Comment: The slider for each main container doesn't slide in FF and I.E.9 but does in chrome.  I've added a <p> tag in each main container but the color of it is black atm...when you click the next/prev button on each main container - the slider should slide to the next slide that currently has a different word in it...again, works fine in chrome, just not in FF nor I.E.9... :(

Comment: @user2732875 stupid question but have you clear cache browser?

Comment: @ A. Wolff would that matter?

Comment: OK...looked again...brilliant demo with very dark letters on ultra dark background....but works for me in FF

Comment: @user2732875 in some way, it could

Comment: @A. Wolff, I just cleared it all and it's still not working on either FF or I.E9

Comment: hmmm...for some odd reason it works just fine in the jsfiddle demo on FF and I.E9, but not on my site in FF or I.E9.  Anyone know the reason to that?

Comment: Note to anybody looking at this: add a CSS rule `p { color: white; }` and you'll have a lot easier time seeing what's happening. It works fine for me in Firefox.

Comment: If it's working in the jsFiddle but not on your page, then just ensure there are no DOM elements on your page with conflicting ids. Also, check your console for any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have the solution to this.  I ended up adding the above code to my site on a different script to see where the issue may be and think that this may be where you are having that issue of where it doesn't work in either FF or IE - as it happened to me as well in the past and sure enough once I implemented your above code it did the same thing.

Check how your html page is referencing your javascript page(s) if you have multiple js pages located in different folders/directories.

For example, Do THIS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Your_Script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/My_Script.js"></script>
```

Rather than THIS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/My_Script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Your_Script.js"></script>
```

If you have multiple folders/directories using JS on your site, you need to make sure whatever page you are working on can check the JS script for the page you are working on first opposed to any other JS scripts you may be using in other folders/directories.  So if you use the first example above that I have provided you, it should work with no problem at all in all browsers.  This happened to me several months ago and it literally took me forever to figure out what was going on.

You want to make sure any jquery you are using is written up and be referenced first on all html pages, then any js scripts you may have should follow that, but make sure they are in the correct order on whatever html page you are working on.

Example of a setup:

Main directory:

--> css folder

-------> Your_css_Script.css

--> images folder

--> js folder (inside 'js folder' you have:)

-------> Your_js_Script.js

-------> JQuery folder

------------> jquery-1.9.1.min.js

--> index.html

--> Another folder - (inside 'Another folder' you have:)

-------> css folder

------------> Your_css2_Script.css

-------> images folder

-------> js folder

------------> Your_js2_Script.js

-------> index2.html

I apologize for the bad diagram above, but hopefully that helps you understand the structure.  So, if you are working on index2.html, and also Your_js2_Script.js, but also need to reference what you have on Your_js_Script.js as well as your jquery script on your index2.html, you would need to reference those scripts on your index2.html page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Your_js2_Script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Your_js_Script.js"></script>
```

By the way, that's a pretty slick looking setup you got going on!  And I hope what I provided helps.